# wordpress category issues

Tags: php, wordpress

setting up a new wordpress blog. slight problem and I've looked everywhere but cant seem to reference it. all over the net the usual syntax for select a specific category on wordpress  sites is http://your.url/category/category_name/

for my site this syntax does not work. I get a page not found error. yet when i actually click on a category i have posted under it gives me a url like this http://www.your.url.co.uk/?cat=51

i can only assume 51 is the cat #

any ideas why the usualy doesnt seem to apply to my site. ps i have latest version installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other sites you have seen this on are probably using category permalinks. Goto your dashboard and look under Settings->Permalinks. There is an optional area for building custom category URLs.

Comment: you my friend are awesome. (never used anything like WP before used to dev my own. all this GUI stuff gets me) will accept your answer in a second... wont let me for 3 more minutes

Comment: Great! Enjoy playing with WP!

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings-permalinks, and custom struckture, type in:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```